# Docker container

Tags: docker, localhost, docker-container

I'm new with docker and my questions seems only stupid but ...

I'm trying to reproduce the docker page => https://docs.docker.com/get-started/02_our_app/. And when I try to start the container he stops.

[image]

Looking for logs >
2023-11-23 21:29:36 Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/index.js'
2023-11-23 21:29:36     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
2023-11-23 21:29:36     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:27)
2023-11-23 21:29:36     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
2023-11-23 21:29:36     at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
2023-11-23 21:29:36   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2023-11-23 21:29:36   requireStack: []
2023-11-23 21:29:36 }

And I already put the index.js into to places but zero doesn't work

[image]

Who can help me?

Comment: Can you show Dockerfile?

Comment: FROM node:18-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yarn install --production
CMD ["node", "src/index.js"]
EXPOSE 3000

Comment: Just move Dockerfile to getting-started-app directory